# Auto mount WebDAV folder

Tags: linux, mount, automount, webdav, davfs2

I want to auto mount WebDAV folder with a bash script. 
My server resources are very poor so I have a memory problem with WebDAV.
Therefore, I have to umount WebDAV folder to clear cache and memory.
But, I have to manually mount WebDAV folders, after that umount command.
Because, system ask to me for credentials for WebDAV folder so, I can't do it with a bash script.

I edited `~/.davfs/secret` file as follows:

```
http://<webdav address> username password
```

after that, I uncommented line `secrets ~/.davfs2/secret` in `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf`  file.

But, system still asks to me for credentials.

How can I auto mount WebDAV?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by keeping everything in `/etc/davfs2/`, i.e. both the `secrets` file and the `davfs2.conf`. A corresponding mount point in `/etc/fstab` that looks similar

```
https://dav.example.com/path/to/store /mnt/ davfs file_mode=0664,dir_mode=2775 0 0
```

allows me to mount the store with `mount /mnt`. I used the [arch linux page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Davfs) as a guide.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197637/davfs-unknown-option-because-of-secrets-file) also seems to be related. The `davfs2` configuration supports a different set of options, depending on whether the config is in `/etc/davfs2`, or in `~/.davfs2`. Not entirely intuitive... :(